# Boxplot vs fivenum: different outcomes?

Tags: r, boxplot

I obtained the following picture by using:

```
boxplot(series,
    col = "orange",
    border = "brown")
```

[image]
The code:

```
boxplot(d$y,
        col = "orange",
        border = "brown")
abline(h = min(d$y), col = "Blue")
abline(h = max(d$y), col = "Yellow")
abline(h = median(d$y), col = "Green")
abline(h = quantile(d$y, c(0.25, 0.75)), col = "Red")
```

produces instead the picture below
[image]
I wanted to see if the boxplot identifies the five number summary. Blue, green and red lines denote minimum, lower-hinge, median, upper-hinge, as expected but I'm not sure about the position of yellow line. Yellow line should be on the top whisker end... Isn't it?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your `series` and `d` dataframes ? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: No, you are taking the maximum value of those `y` values with `max(d$y)`. Therefore, it is in the correct spot.

Comment: Try and grab the output with `x <- boxplot(...)`, compare!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fivenum(x)` function returns the minimum, lower-hinge (25% quantile), median, upper-hinge (75% quantile), and maximum for a list of values. However `boxplot(x)$stats` returns the lower-whisker, lower-hinge (25% quantile), median, upper-hinge (75% quantile), and upper-whisker. Whisker values are generally only calculated for box plots and are by default the most extreme data points that are no more that 1.5 times the interquartile range away from the upper and lower quartiles. These may or may not be the same as the mix and max values.

If you plot the yellow line at the max value, you would expect it go be drawn at the highest value. There are data points located outside of your whiskers.

Answer (score 2):

boxplot by default removes outliers. Sometimes those `max` and `min` may not be inside the range depicted by the whiskers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642865/13046720)).

```
set.seed(42)
x = rnorm(200) * 10
f = fivenum(x)
b = boxplot(x)

abline(h = b$stats)
abline(h = b$out, col = "red")  #Outliers
```

You can kind of extract the values similar to `fivenum` from `boxplot`

```
identical(f, c(min(b$out, b$stats[1]),
  b$stats[2:4],
  max(b$stats[5], b$out)))
#[1] TRUE
```